# What is the best practice for showing a specific node within a specific page?

Tags: nodes, theming

I'm using the boostrap_carousel module which creates a custom content type for a slideshow. I'd like to have a block for one of these carousels to show on the home page. I'd also like to have a carousel embedded on most of the interior pages. What's the best practice to render a specific node that would be created using that content type within the front page and within another node?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a new block view, which selects a specific carousel node, and then choose where you want the block to appear.

[Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) does something similar, where you can create a slideshow in a block from a number of existing images.

Comment: This is the way I'd go as it is easy to build views that select content based on appropriate criteria for this purpose. Eg. 'the latest node of content type X with "promote to front page" set'. If you want more freedom about choosing the node in question, Nodequeue will help. https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if it will render correctly in your situation, but you could try the [Node Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module and then limit the block to whichever pages you want it to show.

> This module allows you to specify content type(s) as being a block.
>   This allows the content managers of the site to edit the block text
>   and title without having to access the block administration page.
>   Users only need edit access to that node in order to edit it.

Comment: This worked really easily with some block template overriding.

Now to figure out how to show this content type within another node.